# Call ember route from server side rendered app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

So I currently have a rails 6.0 and ember (octane) 3.14 app. Ember is being included into the server-side rendered rails template. I configured the ember app to have a rootElement and rootURL as mentioned here: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/configuring-ember/embedding-applications/

This way, ember gets included fine. Problem is now, I would like to use an href or button from the rails template to call a route in the ember app.

My rails application.html:

```
<div id="ember" class="ember-application">
  <a href="/app/accounts/new">new Account</a>
</div>
```

The rootURL is configured to /app and the rootElement is #ember

An ember LinkTo element does not seem to have any special event handlers or anything. Those seem to sit on the rootElement so I had the idea of delegating the click event to the rootElement but no luck so far...

Any ideas how I could get this to work?

Comment: You may want to check out https://github.com/intercom/ember-href-to.  Under the hood, it actually ends up intercepting the click event for all a tags, so that might work in your case

Comment: Can you describe why this doesn't work now? Ember routes are entirely defined by the URL so you can type a URL in, bookmark it, or follow an external link and all should work as long as ember exists at that URL.

Comment: There is no difference between typing the url and just directly entering the full url in the href. It should still "work", provided your server is correctly returning the same index.html at /app/accounts/new.